# Is it possible to have two different volume level?

Tags: audio, audacious

I am playing background music on audacious player. At the same time I am watching youtube videos. The problem is that the volume on Audacious is the Master volume, so it is impossible to have volume down on audacious and high volume whilst I am watching youtube videos.

Is there a way to have a different volume for Audacious?

Comment: Are you using a sound server (Pulseaudio, Jack, …)? If you don't know what that is, what distribution and desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Enabling through the Sound Preferences

You can open up the sound preferences dialog of the desktop and within it is a tab called Applications. From here you can control the individual volume for each app that is currently running.

*desktop icon for speaker*

[image: ss of speaker icon]

*sound prefs dialog*

[image: ss of sound prefs]

#### PulseAudio installed?

Make sure that you have packages such as the following installed so that you have pulse audio available. I'm showing my Fedora 14 system, but the packages will likely be called something similar on other distros.

```
$ yum install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils pulseaudio-libs
```

#### References

- [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/)

Comment: In audacious there is no sound preference menu options

Comment: @milarepa - it's not in audacious, it's under the speaker icon for your desktop.

Comment: I install Kmix as a sound tray icon, and I can see that audacious is on a separate tab, but when I move the volume, it changes as well in the master volume.

Comment: @milarepa - what are you on OS wise? Are you using KDE? Add that to your Q.

Comment: Should clarify that this answer is dependent upon PulseAudio. Additionally PulseAudio is the only way to have per-application volume control. Alsa cannot do it by itself (don't know about Jack though).

Comment: @Patrick - thanks for mentioning that. I believe this can be done with Jack as well, though I'm not sure how.

Comment: @milarepa - do you have pulse audio installed?

Comment: @sim - No, I didn't have it installed. So that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: @milarepa - can you write that up as an answer, or I can add it to mine and you can mark it as accepted so that others know your issue has been resolved.

Comment: @ slm Please add the answer and I will mark it. Thanks

Comment: @milarepa - let me know if I should add more.